# Pixi2Pix Gan Caught TypeError in DataLoader worker process 0

Tags: python, generative-adversarial-network

I am  trying to coded a Pix2Pix GAN but I am getting this error with my Data loader:

```
Caught TypeError in DataLoader worker process 0.
```

here is my dataset class:

```
class Pix2PixDataset(Dataset):
 def __init__(self, data_points, transforms = None):
  self.data_points = data_points
  self.transforms = transforms
  self.resize = T.Resize((512,512))

def __getitem__(self, index) :
  image = self.resize(read_a_image(self.data_points[index].reference_image))
  y_label = self.resize(read_a_image(self.data_points[index].drawing))
  if self.transforms:
   image = self.transforms(image)
   y_label = self.transforms(y_label)
  return(image, y_label)
def __len__(self):
 return len(self.data_points)
```

and here is the code for my dataloader:

```
test_loader2 = DataLoader(traindataset, batch_size=Batch, shuffle=True,  num_workers = Num_Workers, collate_fn = transforms.RandomRotation(degrees=360), pin_memory=True)
for test_images, test_drawing in test_loader2:
 display(test_images) 
 plt.show()
display(test_drawing)
break
```

again I am doing a Pix to Pix so both my x and y(label) has to be an images tensor.
How can I do this ?
I saw on this site but that someone else got this same error and they was told that y has to be an int, but again I am doing a Pix2Pix gans so both my x and y are images
so how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first check the datatype for *self.data_points[index].reference_image* and *self.data_points[index].drawing* and make sure they are of the right tensor types (I am assuming here that T in T.Resize is for torchvision.transforms). Printing image.type() and y_label.type() will be helpful in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the  problem was

```
 collate_fn = transforms.RandomRotation(degrees=360)
```

in my data loader constructor. So I removed it and it started working